# Real GHC RTS memory usage

Tags: haskell, garbage-collection, ghc, heap-memory

Now when [Ganesh Sittampalam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082375/haskell-ghc-runtime-memory-usage-or-what-do-i-do-wrong/4082434#4082434) shed some light on GHC RTS memory management I have another question: what means exist to check, how much of allocated memory is "bound" and how much of it is not used at the moment?

Comment: For reference, the improvement in GHC 7 that he was talking about is summarized here: http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/698

Answer (score 3):

You want heap profiling: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/users_guide/prof-heap.html